# find the attribute value by entered in textbox and get there parent attribute value

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

i have this type of xml file:-

```
<root>
    <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="india">
        <child_2 entity_id = "2" value="gujarat">
            <child_3 entity_id = "3" value="Ahemdabad"/>
            <child_4 entity_id = "4" value="Surat"/>
            <child_5 entity_id = "5" value="Rajkot"/>           
        </child_2>
    </child_1>
</root>
```

i have one textbox in them i enter any city name eg. Surat if Surat is on my xml file then return there parent attribute value eg. gujarat.
thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120041/get-parent-element-node-when-child-node-is-match Please check i add my try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath

```
//*[@value='Surat']/parent::*/@value
```

Just replace 'Surat' with a variable