# Get parent element node when child node is matched

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var xml;
$.get(
    "code.xml",  
    function(data) { xml=data; },
    "html"
);
function get_list(){
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
  $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
  $title = $xml.find('[value="'+$('#select').val()+'"]');
  $nodes = $title.find('*');
  var result='';
  $nodes.each(function(){
    result += $(this).attr('value');
    result += ' ';
  });
  $("#result").html(result);
}
</script>
</head>
<input type="text" id="select">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Search" onclick="get_list()" >
<div id="result">
</div>
</html>
```

This is my `xml` file:

```
 <root>
    <child_1 entity_id = "1" value="india">
        <child_2 entity_id = "2" value="gujarat">
            <child_3 entity_id = "3" value="Ahemdabad"/>
            <child_4 entity_id = "4" value="Surat"/>
            <child_5 entity_id = "5" value="Rajkot"/>           
        </child_2>
    </child_1>
    <child_6 entity_id = "6" value="Rasia">
        <child_7 entity_id = "7" value="state">
            <child_8 entity_id = "8" value="cty"/>
            <child_9 entity_id = "9" value="cty1"/>
            <child_10 entity_id = "10" value="cty2"/>           
        </child_2>
    </child_6>
</root>
```

> *With this code I get the `child node value`.*

I wanted something, like  when i enter in `textbox` any of *city name*: **Ahemdabad**, **Surat**, **Rajkot**; then its match on my xml file returns me `country name` like **India**.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want the result to be `india`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var xml;
$.get(
    "code.xml",  
    function(data) { 
        xml=data; 
    },
    "html"
);
function get_list(){
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $title = $xml.find('[value="'+$('#select').val()+'"]');
    var ctrs = $xml.find('root').children();
    $("#result").html($title.closest(ctrs).attr('value'));
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/24ZboPRGcbAb8VxNyNrb?p=preview)

Comment: its not possible `('child_1')` manual b'coz i have huge xml file so then i am enter just node 2 child like in my xml updated... cty then output is Rasia... so not manual possible... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath

```
//*[@value='Ahemdabad']/parent::*/@value
```

Just replace 'Ahemdabad' with the desired city name